# select IN utilizando entity query

Tags: linq-to-entities

Como faço para reproduzir a seguinte consulta usando ef core, ou no LINQ?

```
SELECT ob.PK_OBJETIVO,
   ev.NM_EVENTO,
   ifi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
   imi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
   ire.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO,
   (ifi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO + imi.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO + ire.QT_NOTA_IMPACTO)/3 AS 
Media
FROM AVALIACAO_IMPACTO AS ai
INNER JOIN EVENTO AS EV ON ev.PK_EVENTO = ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_EVENTO
INNER JOIN OBJETIVO AS ob ON ob.PK_OBJETIVO = 
ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_OBJETIVO
INNER JOIN IMPACTO_FINANCEIRO AS ifi ON ifi.PK_IMPACTO_FINANCEIRO = 
ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO1
INNER JOIN IMPACTO_MISSAO AS imi ON IMI.PK_IMPACTO_MISSAO = 
AI.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO2
INNER JOIN IMPACTO_REPUTACAO AS IRE ON IRE.PK_IMPACTO_REPUTACAO = 
AI.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_IMPACTO3
WHERE ai.FK_AVALIACAO_IMPACTO_OBJETIVO IN
    (SELECT OBJ.PK_OBJETIVO
     FROM OBJETIVO AS OBJ
     WHERE OBJ.FK_OBJETIVO_PROCESSO = 3)
```

Fiz a seguinte tentativa:

```
var queryImpactos = await _context.AvaliacaoImpacto
            .Where(e => _context.Objetivo.Select(o => 
o.ProcessoID).Contains(planoRiscos.Auditoria.ProcessoID))
            .Include(e => e.Evento).Include(e => e.Objetivo)
            .Include(e => e.ImpactoFinanceiro).Include(e => 
e.ImpactoMissao).Include(e => e.ImpactoReputacao).ToListAsync();
```

planoRiscos.Auditoria.ProcessoID retorna o id que preciso, seria o número 3 da consulta SQL pura, mas o resultado da consulta linq está retornando todos os registros da tabela avaliacao_impacto, no entanto eu preciso apenas dos registros onde a fk_objetivo em avaliacao_impacto exista dentro da tabela objetivo onde a fk_processo em objetivo seja igual ao parâmetro passado (planoRiscos.Auditoria.ProcessoID).

Comment: Olá! Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt! Poderia nos mostrar algum código que já tentou?

Comment: Obrigado, editei a pergunta e postei o código que tentei